# PrimeNG TurboTable - strange virtual scroll behaviour - keeps doubling event.rows

Tags: angular, primeng, ngrx, primeng-turbotable

I've implemented a custom Grid component that uses PrimeNG TurboTable and NgRx and I've added the virtual scroll feature to it using the built-in TurboTable virtual scroll. It is also lazy loading, with `onLazyLoad` handler. However, I get this strange behaviour when `onLazyLoad` is called as I am scrolling through the grid results.

```
onLazyLoad called with event.first=0 and event.rows=40
onLazyLoad called with event.first=0 and event.rows=80
onLazyLoad called with event.first=0 and event.rows=160
onLazyLoad called with event.first=0 and event.rows=320
onLazyLoad called with event.first=0 and event.rows=640
onLazyLoad called with event.first=0 and event.rows=1280
```

So there are 2 problems:

1. `event.first` always stays 0
2. `event.rows` keeps doubling to very
   high values

I thought that it's a bug in PrimeNG but when I've tried to reproduce it with a simple StackBlitz, there it is behaving correctly.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-primeng-virtualscroll-issue

I see this on StackBlitz:

```
loadDataOnScroll is called with event.first=0 and event.rows=40
loadDataOnScroll is called with event.first=20 and event.rows=40
loadDataOnScroll is called with event.first=40 and event.rows=40
loadDataOnScroll is called with event.first=80 and event.rows=40
loadDataOnScroll is called with event.first=120 and event.rows=40
```

So `event.rows` stays constant as it is supposed to and `event.first` increases normally.

Looks like something is triggering this from the way I use the TurboTable, but I don't know what. What could be the issue?
Here is the relevant code from my grid component:

**The lazy load handler:**

```
onLazyLoad(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    // TODO - In this StackBlitz it behaves correctly
    // https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-primeng-virtualscroll-issue
    console.log(
        `onLazyLoad called with event.first=${event.first} and event.rows=${
            event.rows
        }`
    );

    // TODO - This state should be handled by NgRx as well.
    this.loading = true;
    this.filters = {};

    const hasPagination = this.settings.features.Pagination;

    // TODO - Tweak the behavior of virtual scroll skipCount/maxResultCount
    // based on testing results.
    // The default behavior is a bit strange, skipCount is always 0
    // and maxResultCount keeps getting doubled.
    let pageSize = event.rows ? event.rows : GridConfig.PageSize;
    this.filters.maxResultCount = pageSize;
    this.filters.skipCount = event.first ? event.first : 0;
    this.filters.ignorePagination = !hasPagination;

    if (event.sortOrder && event.sortField) {
        const sortingDirection = event.sortOrder > 0 ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
        this.filters.sorting = event.sortField + ' ' + sortingDirection;
    }

    if (event.globalFilter) {
        this.filters.filter = event.globalFilter;
    }

    if (event.filters) {
        this.filters.columnFilters = this.buildColumnFilters(event.filters);
    }

    this.filters.parentFilters = this.parentFilters; // this works only with client-side caching & filtering

    if (this.settings.features.ClientSideCaching) {
        // Load only once
        this.gridLoaded().subscribe(loaded => {
            if (loaded) {
                this.store.dispatch(
                    new this.settings.stateActions.FilterClientSide(
                        this.filters
                    )
                );
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.store.dispatch(
            new this.settings.stateActions.Read(this.filters)
        );
    }
}
```

**The parameters I pass in the template:**

```
<p-table
        #dataTable
        [value]="(data$ | async)?.items"
        [loading]="loading"
        [lazy]="true"
        [virtualScroll]="!settings.features.Pagination"
        [virtualRowHeight]="35"
        [scrollable]="!settings.features.Pagination"
        (onLazyLoad)="onLazyLoad($event)"
        [autoLayout]="true"
        [columns]="selectedColumns"
        [paginator]="settings.features.Pagination"
        scrollHeight="400px"
        [resizableColumns]="true"
        [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10, 20, 30]"
        [totalRecords]="(data$ | async)?.totalCount"
        [rows]="(this.settings.states.Search | async)?.maxResultCount"
        [stateStorage]="this.settings.persistence?.stateStorage"
        [stateKey]="this.settings.persistence?.stateKey"
        [(selection)]="selectedRows"
        [selectionMode]="this.settings.rowSelection?.selectionMode || null"
        (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)"
        [dataKey]="this.settings.rowSelection?.dataKey || null"
    >
```

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happened because `event.rows` is persisted in the NgRx store and I was reusing it when building the filters and every time `onLazyLoad` gets called it would get doubled.

Here I initialize `rows` with the NgRx store value:

```
[rows]="(this.settings.states.Search | async)?.maxResultCount"
```

Then inside `onLazyLoad` I was using `event.rows`:

```
let pageSize = event.rows ? event.rows : GridConfig.PageSize;
this.filters.maxResultCount = pageSize;
```

PrimeNG doubles `event.rows` in their code for virtual scroll and it gets persisted into the NgRx store when I call `FilterClientSide` action. Then the template gets that new value and on a subsequent `onLazyLoad` it gets doubled again.

The solution that worked for me was to just set a constant for this:

```
if (this.settings.features.VirtualScroll) {
    pageSize = GridConfig.PageSize * 2;
} else {
    pageSize = event.rows ? event.rows : 10;
}
```

Comment: I am not using NgRx store, but I still have the same problem. The onLazyLoad() method gets called twice at initial loading of the table. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

This could be because in the https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-primeng-virtualscroll-issue you have a hard-coded total record count parameter to `<p-table>`.
Where as in your actual implementation you may be setting to something smaller than your dataset size or 0 *(Looks like you have an observable there. Check on what does it evaluate to. Try setting some large number greater than your dataset to see if this theory is correct)*.

Check on what does `[totalRecords]="(data$ | async)?.totalCount"` parameter evaluates to you in your implementation for `<p-table>`.
Hopefully this will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this is not the case. I've tried hardcoding 1000 to `totalRecords` (which is greater than my dataset) and the behaviour is the same. I think somewhere the pagination settings are persisted and keep getting doubled instead of just getting recalculated from the base pagesize